# Trying to open android app in javascript and fall back to play store if the app is not installed

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery

I'm trying to add a banner on our website for android users that use a browser instead of our webapp

So I've a link

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kronos_sport.kronossport" class="kronos-link-openstore">Open</a>
```

What i'm doing so far in javascript

```
jQuery(domNode).find('.kronos-link-openstore').each(function () {
    
    jQuery(this).click(function () {
        triggerAppOpen();
        return false;
    });
    
    var fallbackToStore = function() {
        window.location.replace("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kronos_sport.kronossport");
    };
    var openApp = function() {
        window.open('kronos://');
    };
    var triggerAppOpen = function() {
        openApp();
        setTimeout(fallbackToStore, 250);
    };
    
});
```

The user is redirected to the store but the app does not open (the scheme is correct)

Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a timeout issue with  `setTimeout(fallbackToStore, 100);` the app launch (and crash instantly but that's another problem)